# Difference between custom metadata and static functions?

Tags: actionscript-3

Custom metadata in Actionscript classes are very cool. You can put anything in square brackets in front of classes, functions, and variables; tell the compiler to include it (by name) in the SWF; and use describeType() to retrieve it.

```
[MyMetaData(name1=value1, name2=value2)]
```

Add to "Additional compiler arguments”

```
-keep-as3-metadata+=MyMetaData
```

And use describeType() to find those items with that meta-data

```
var typeDescriptionXML : XML = flash.utils.describeType(aType);

var itemsWithMyMetaData : XMLList = 
    classXML.factory.metadata.(@name == "MyMetaData");
```

---

Static functions, on the other hand are rather straight-forward:

```
public static function myStaticFunction() : Object
{
    var result : Object = new Object({name1: "value1", name2: "value2"});
    return result;
}
```

While I would like static functions to be virtual, they do what they are supposed to do.

---

What advantage does meta-data have over static functions for *class level* items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume there are some performance issues related to using metadata. `describeType` isn't cheap, then you have to pull what you want out of the large XML tree.

There are certainly type related issues. Even your second example where you send an `Object` would be much better if the data was inside a class. It is *very* rare for me these days to use `Object`s anywhere in my code except when I am prototyping. And your code could be much more succinct:

```
public static function myStaticFunction():Object
{
    return { name1: "value1", name2: "value2" };
}
```

Additionally static class functions can interact with other static class functions and static properties:

```
package
{
public class StaticClass
{
    private static const SOME_DATA:int = 0;
    private static const SOME_STRING:String = "Hello World";

    private static var count:int = 0;

    public static function printCount():void
    {
        trace(SOME_STRING, SOME_DATA, count++);
    }
}

}
```

I can imagine uses for metadata (e.g. for library code that doesn't require implementing an interface) and I can see why Flex uses them for that purpose (e.g. build lists of remote-objects, events, bindables) but I would never recommend them for normal use.

Answer (score 3):

I moreless agree with James. However, **there is one advantage for metadata: uniform access** ...

if you have an array of classes, and you kind of know, that each of them has a property `classMetaData`, then this code won't work:

```
for each (var c:Class in arrayOfClass) 
     trace(c.getData());
```

this will:

```
for each (var c:* in arrayOfClass) 
     trace(c.getData());
```

but it's rather quirky, requiring that EVERY class has that static property, and on top of that `c.getData()` is also of type `*` ...

accessing metadata through `describeType` always works good ... the worst thing that can happen is, that you wind up iterating an empty `XMLList`, but there's nothing wrong with that in the end ... if you encapsulate that traversal into some utility class or something like that, then you end up with a solid solution ... and if it uses a cache for retrieved data, you are not really slower than with static variable access ...

in the end, i think the idea is simple: **you should use metadata-tags to capture meta-data and actionscript to capture data** ... the distinction is not 100% obvious, but in the end, it's up to you to draw the line between the two ...

greetz

back2dos